# Opacity transition not working, z-index issue?

Tags: html, css, z-index, transition, opacity

Before I went and reset some of the default properties, everything was working fine, now my opacity effect over each  is not working anymore. No matter how much I play around with the z-index placement, it doesn't seem to work.

As well, my  "like" button isn't positioning correctly in each  is not positioning repeatedly in the same location.

Could someone please look at it for me? Thank you.

**This is the HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 

<head> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/index.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
<title>Website Project</title>
<meta charset="utf-8"/> 
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <h1>Vancouver Island University</h1>
    <h1>Health and Wellness Community</h1>
    <h1>"No more excuses"</h1>
    <a href="index.html"><img id="logo" src="Images/VIU-logo-small.jpg" alt="VIU logo" title="VIU logo"></a>
</header>
<img src="Images/websitebackground.jpg" id="background" alt="website background image">
<nav>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="navigation"/>
            <label for="navigation" name="navigation">Events and Workshops</label>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Upcoming Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Upcoming Workshops</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Request an Event or Workshop</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="navigation2"/>
            <label for="navigation2" name="navigation2">Resources</label>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Nutrition Resources</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Physical Activity Resources</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Mental Health Resources</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Spiritual Health Resources</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Social Health Resources</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Medical Health Resources</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Volunteer Opportunities</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<section>
    <div class="sectionalblocks">
        <a target="_self" href="#">
            <img src="Images/blog.png" alt="Blog Article">
            <span class="text-content"><span> Blog </span></span>
        </a><iframe class="likebutton" src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&width=153&layout=button_count&action=like&size=large&show_faces=true&share=true&height=46&appId" width="153" height="46" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="sectionalblocks">
        <div id="articlepreview"><h2>Glorifying Exhaustion: The student crisis</h2><p>It’s that time of year again; between the midterms, papers, and looming final exams, people start to brag about how they are on their sixth extra-large triple-shot coffee, or that they pulled an all-nighter to get their paper in on time...</p></div>
        <a target="_blank" href="http://www.thenav.ca/2016/11/16/glorifying-exhaustion-the-student-crisis/">
            <img id="articleimage" src="Images/articleimage.jpg" alt="Resource Article">
            <span class="text-content"><span>Resources</span></span>

        </a><iframe id="likebutton" src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&width=153&layout=button_count&action=like&size=large&show_faces=true&share=true&height=46&appId" width="153" height="46" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="sectionalblocks">
        <a target="_self" href="#">
            <img src="Images/upcomingevents.png" alt="Upcoming Events Article">
            <span class="text-content"><span>Upcoming Events</span></span>

        </a><iframe class="likebutton" src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&width=153&layout=button_count&action=like&size=large&show_faces=true&share=true&height=46&appId" width="153" height="46" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="sectionalblocks">
        <a target="_self" href="#">
            <img src="Images/volunteer.png" alt="Volunteer Article">
            <span class="text-content"><span>Volunteer</span></span>

        </a><iframe class="likebutton" src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&width=153&layout=button_count&action=like&size=large&show_faces=true&share=true&height=46&appId" width="153" height="46" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="sectionalblocks">
        <a target="_self" href="http://blog.myfitnesspal.com/10-nutritious-smoothies-250-calories/">
            <img src="Images/smoothies.jpg" alt="Nutrition Article">
            <span class="text-content"><span>Nutrition</span></span>

        </a><iframe class="likebutton" src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&width=153&layout=button_count&action=like&size=large&show_faces=true&share=true&height=46&appId" width="153" height="46" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
        </div>
    <div class="sectionalblocks">
        <div id="articlepreview"><h2>I Want To Be With Someone Who Knows What It’s Like To Be Broken</h2><p>When seeking a partner, most people have pretty generic things that they’re looking for. They want a man to be handsome, smart, successful, funny, kind. But most qualities that people rattle off don’t go much deeper than that. For me, there’s something rare and unconventional I’m looking for in another person. A quality that I know will mean I truly found the right partner...</p></div>
        <a target="_blank" href="http://thoughtcatalog.com/kelly-bishop/2016/03/i-want-to-be-with-someone-who-knows-what-its-like-to-be-broken/">
            <img id="articleimage" src="Images/mentalhealth.jpg" alt="Mental Health Article">
            <span class="text-content"><span>Resources</span></span>

        </a><iframe id="likebutton" src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&width=153&layout=button_count&action=like&size=large&show_faces=true&share=true&height=46&appId" width="153" height="46" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
    </div>
</section>

<aside>
    <ul id="emergencycontact">
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="contact"/>
            <label for="contact" name="contact">Contact</label>
            <ul>
                <h3 class="heading">Emergency Contacts</h3>
                <h4>Assistance Phones</h4>
                <p class="underline"><a href="https://www2.viu.ca/facilities/docs/VIU-AssistancePhones-Map.pdf">Location Map Link</a></p>
                <h4>Vancouver Island University Counselling Services</h4>
                <p class="italic">Monday - Friday; 8 am - 4 pm</p>
                <p>Nanaimo Campus   Phone: 250-740-6416</p>
                <p>Cowichan Campus Phone: 250-746-3509</p>
                <p>Parksville Campus    Phone: 250-248-2096</p>
                <p>Powell River Campus  Phone: (604) 485-2878</p>
                <h4>Mental Health Walk-in Clinic (Crisis Counselling)</h4>
                <p class="italic">Monday - Friday; 10am - 6pm</p>
                <p>Nanaimo  Phone: 250-739-5710</p>
                <p>Location: 203-2000 Island Highway North, Nanaimo, BC V9S 5W3</p>
                <p class="underline"><a href="http://www.viha.ca/mhas/locations/nanaimo/">Island Health Website</a></p>
                <h4>Vancouver Island Crisis Line</h4>
                <p class="italic">7 days a week/24 hours a day</p>
                <p>Phone: 1-888-494-3888</p>
                <p class="underline"><a href="http://www.vicrisis.ca/">Crisis Line Website</a></p>
                <p class="contactheading">Haven Transition House Crisis Line Support for abused women and their children</p>
                <p class="italic">7 days a week/24 hours a day</p>
                <p>Phone: 250-756-0616</p>
                <h4>On Campus Emergency</h4>
                <p class="contactheading">Emergency, First Aid, Security, Ambulance, Fire, Police, Bomb Threat</p>
                <p class="italic">7 days a week/24 hours a day</p>
                <p>Office/Internal Phone Nanaino/Cowichan Phone: 6600</p>
                <p>Office/Internal Phone Powell River   Phone: 8121 or 911</p>
                <p>Office/Internal Phone Parksville Phone: 951-3000 or 911</p>
                <p class="contactheading">Emergency Phone Push button</p>
                <p>Pay Phone Nanaimo    Phone: 740-6600</p>
                <p>Pay Phone Cowichan   Phone: 1-250-740-6600</p>
                <p>Pay Phone Powell River   Phone: 604-485-2878</p>
                <p>Pay Phone Parksville Phone: 951-3000 or 911</p>
                <h4>Off Campus Emergency</h4>
                <p class="contactheading">Police, Fire, and Ambulance Services</p>
                <p class="italic">7 days a week/24 hours a day</p>
                <p>Phone: 911</p>
                <h4>Nanaimo Regional General Hospital</h4>
                <p class="italic">7 days a week/24 hours a day</p>
                <p>Phone: 250-754-2141</p>
                <p>Location: 1200 Dufferin Crescent, Nanaimo, BC V9S 5R6</p>
                <h4>Email contact</h4>
                <p class="underline">behealthy@viu.ca</p>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</aside>
<footer id="validator">
    <a href="https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fmediastudies.viu.ca%2FStudents%2F577081557%2FLabs%2Flab02.html"><img src="Images/html-validator.jpg" alt="HTML validator badge"></a> | <a href="https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmediastudies.viu.ca%2FStudents%2F577081557%2FLabs%2Findex.html&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en"><img src="Images/css-validator.gif" alt="CSS validator badge"></a>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

**This is the CSS**

```
 html 
{
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%    
}

body
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    max-width:100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden; /*Disable horizontal scrollbar*/
}

#background /*Background image*/
{
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0;  
  /* Preserve aspet ratio */
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  z-index: -4;
  opacity: .5;
}
*
{
    font-family: 'Roboto', Tahoma, Arial;
}
header
{
    background-color: #144762; /*VIU colours*/
    padding: 30px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-top: -10px;
}
#logo
{
    float: left;
    top: 40px;
    left: 40px;
    position: absolute;

}
h1
{
    margin-left: 500px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

/*Navigation Menu, <nav>*/
#menu /*entire box*/
{
    list-style: none;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-color: #ecffec;/*#444 the Navigator nav color*/
    padding: 0; 
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#menu li /*text box*/
{
    margin-right: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #ecffec;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#menu ul /*Actual dropdown menu*/
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
    list-style: none;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-color: #ecffec;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    line-height: 15px;
    width: auto;
}
#menu ul li /*text inside dropdown menu*/
{
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 15px;
    min-width: 150px;
}
#menu a:link,
#menu a:visited,
#menu label {
 display: block;
 font-family: 'Roboto', Tahoma;
 font-size: 0.75em;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: left;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #000;
 padding: 5px;
}

#menu li:hover,
#menu input:checked + label {
 background-color: #ffd98a;
 border: 1px solid #000;
}

#menu li:hover ul,
#menu input:checked ~ ul {
 display: block;
}

#menu input {
display: none;
}isited, #menu label { display: block; font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; text-decoration: none; color: #000; padding: 5px; }

/*Contact information*/
#emergencycontact /*entire box, <aside>*/
{
    list-style: none;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-color: #ecffec;
    padding: 0; 
    position: fixed;/*added this*/
    width: 120px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 5;

}
#emergencycontact li /*text box*/
{
    border: 1px solid #ecffec;
    position: relative;
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#emergencycontact ul /*Actual popout window*/
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 27px;
    right:0;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    display: none;
    list-style: none;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-color: #ecffec;
    padding: 0 0 26px 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: none;
    line-height: 15px;
    overflow: scroll;
    font-weight: normal;
}
#emergencycontact a:link, #emergencycontact a:visited
{
    display: block;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    padding: 5px;
}
#emergencycontact li:hover,
#emergencycontact input:checked + label 
{
  background-color: #ffd98a;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

#emergencycontact li:hover ul,
#emergencycontact input:checked ~ ul 
{
  display: block;
}

#emergencycontact input 
{
  display: none;
}

#emergencycontact label 
{
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
}
p.underline
{
    text-decoration: underline;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
p.italic
{
    font-style: italic;
}
.heading
{
    text-align: center;
}
h4{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
p.contactheading{
    font-weight: bold;
}
h4, p.contactheading, p.italic, #emergencycontact p/*text inside dropdown menu*/
{
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px;
}

/*Sectional blocks*/
section
{
    margin: 40px 23px;
    width: 100%;
}
div.sectionalblocks 
{
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    z-index: -4; 
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}
div.sectionalblocks img /*Image underneath sectional blocks*/
{
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    position: relative;



}
#articleimage /*Image underneath article*/
{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -3;
    filter: brightness(80%);
    opacity: 0.8;
}
#articlepreview /*Text inside article sectional blocks*/
{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    height: 400px;
    width: 360px;
    padding: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: white;
}
#articlepreview h2 /*Header text inside article sectional blocks*/
{
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: white;
}
span.text-content /*Text inside sectional blocks*/
{
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
    font-family:"proxima nova",sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 30px;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    display:table;
    opacity:0;
    z-index:5;
    padding:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
    -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
    -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
    transition: opacity 500ms;
}
span.text-content span 
{
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
span.text-content:hover 
{
    opacity:1;
}
iframe.likebutton
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 5;
}


/*Footer*/
#validator
{
    position: relative;
    bottom:0;
    left: 20px;
    width:100%;

}
```

Here is the live version: https://jsfiddle.net/nxb8bann/1/
**NOTE: The hover opacity transition effect seems to be working here, but not on my browser (chrome/firefox)**

Answer (score 1):

Your footer section is overlapping your main content. You need to make sure the footer positioning is after the main content where your like buttons are.

```
#validator { clear:both; }
```

Comment: it's still not working, I tried it on my Jsfiddle but it actually doesn't work there either. Still not working on my chrome/firefox browser as well. https://jsfiddle.net/nxb8bann/4/

Answer (score 0):

As you say, it seems to work fine in a fiddle so it may be something else in your webpage conflicting.

as for the position of the 'like' button, you need to change this to absolute position. like this.

```
div.sectionalblocks iframe {
    position: absolute;
    left: 15px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

take a look at the amended fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/4j5Lkvsc/

Comment: Thanks, the above fixed it for me. As for the opacity transition, I don't know what's going on, it works in jsfiddle/codepen fine, but not on my own chrome/firefox browser? It doesn't actually let me click or anything either, so I thought it might be a layering issue, but nothing seems to work! :(